# Mimic a signed on client to webserver

Tags: python, authentication

I've tried to look around for an answer but didn't find any - so I'm asking here:

I am trying to debug my code to see something that isn't working. What I am trying to do is I've logged on to a web page using Firefox. I am using Firebug to capture request/response headers. This page is about 2/3 levels deep after login.

I am trying to load this 3rd page through my Python code by replicating the cookies and the request headers. But the server somehow knows that the request is from an unauthenticated client and responds with the login page.
AFAIK, the only cookies are an .ASPXAUTH cookie and an ASP.NET_SessionId which I have verified are being passed from my python code.

**So my question:** How do I mimic/trick the server into thinking that the request is coming from an authenticated client.

Additional notes:
a) I am using the same machine for logging onto the webpage via firefox and for running the Python code. So the local ip is the same.
b) I am logged on to the web page at the same time I am trying to replicate the python request (i.e session is active).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in cookie-based authentication. If speed is not that much of an issue, or the webserver requires JavaScript to work, the easiest solution would be in using selenium. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  # Start a firefox instance in "WebDriver" mode
browser.get("http://www.example.com")  # load the page
assert "Example Domain" in browser.title  # make sure that we have the right page
elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("a")  # find the only link
elem.click()  # click on the link
time.sleep(0.2)  # Let the page load
# etc. etc.
```

You can fill out forms, wait for some specific content to appear etc.